# Building a list of random multiplication examples

Tags: list-manipulation, education

I want to make a list of multiplications of randomly selected numbers that proceeds until a product greater than 50 is generated.

How can I obtain such a list where each element is a product and its two factors?

Here is the code I tried.

```
L = {0};
While[Last[L] < 50, 
  rp = RandomReal[{1, 10}, 2];
  L = Append[L, rp[[1]] rp[[2]]]];
Print[Rest[L]]
rp
```

> `{3.57895, 11.2685, ..., 66.5699}`

But I want

> ```
> {{1.325, 2.701094, 3.57895}, {2.1481, 5.2458,  11.2685}, ...., {8.45152, 7.87668, 66.5699}}
> ```

Comment: I cannot figure out what you want from your post.

Comment: It should be `L = {{0, 0}};
While[Last[Last[L]] < 50, rp = RandomReal[{1, 10}, 2];
  L = Append[L, {rp[[1]], rp[[2]], rp[[1]] rp[[2]]}]];
Rest@L`. Or `{##, Times@##} & @@@ Rest@NestWhileList[RandomReal[{1, 10}, 2] &, {0}, Times @@ # < 50 &]`

Comment: @xzczd your code is working thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do what you ask for using `While`.

```
SeedRandom[42];
Module[{list = {}, r1, r2, r1r2},
  While[True,
    {r1, r2} = RandomReal[{1, 10}, 2];
    AppendTo[list, {r1, r2, r1r2 = r1 r2}];
     If[r1r2 >= 50, Break[]]];
 list]
```

But here is a somewhat simpler and more efficient way.

```
SeedRandom[42];
Reap[
  Do[
    Module[{r1, r2, r1r2},
      {r1, r2} = RandomReal[{1, 10}, 2];
      Sow[{r1, r2, r1r2 = r1 r2}];
      If[r1r2 >= 50, Break[]]], ∞]][[2, 1]]
```

Evaluating either of the above expressions gives

> ```
> {{4.83315, 4.51921, 21.842}, {4.12362, 5.08367, 20.9631}, 
>  {6.00367, 3.60252, 21.6284}, {3.67163, 2.85767, 10.4923}, 
>  {3.92653, 9.75992, 38.3226}, {3.32916, 5.95523, 19.826},
>  {7.45558, 7.78917, 58.0728}}
> ```

#### Notes

1. I use [`Module`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html) to localize the variables holding intermediate results.
2. In this case iterating with [`Do`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html) is more efficient than a While-loop
3. [`Sow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) and [`Reap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html) provide an efficient way to accumulate the results within an iterator like `Do`.